# Adding a new column where each element is a cumulative list of elements of another column

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df <- data.frame(category=c("cat1","cat1","cat2","cat1","cat2","cat2","cat1","cat2"),
                 value=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
```

I want to add a new column to the above dataframe which lists the elements of `value` up to that point, grouped by `category`. In my head it would look something like:

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  mutate(value_list=list(some_sort_of_cumulative_identity_function(value)))
```

so the desired output would be

```
  category value value_list
1     cat1     1  1
2     cat1     2  c(1,2)
3     cat2     3  3
4     cat1     4  c(1,2,4)
5     cat2     5  c(3,5)
6     cat2     6  c(3,5,6)
7     cat1     7  c(1,2,4,7)
8     cat2     8  c(3,5,6,8)
```

where the elements of value_list are lists.

Comment: Or use `accumulate` i.e. `df %>% group_by(category) %>% mutate(vlist = accumulate(value, c)`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is currently idiomatic within the tidyverse:

```
library(purrr)
df %>% group_by(category) %>% mutate(vlist = accumulate(value, c))

# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   category [2]
  category value     vlist
    <fctr> <dbl>    <list>
1     cat1     1 <dbl [1]>
2     cat1     2 <dbl [2]>
3     cat2     3 <dbl [1]>
4     cat1     4 <dbl [3]>
5     cat2     5 <dbl [2]>
6     cat2     6 <dbl [3]>
7     cat1     7 <dbl [4]>
8     cat2     8 <dbl [4]>
```

(Thanks to @akrun who commented at the same time.)

The base R analogue is `Reduce(c, value, accumulate=TRUE)`.